# Car out of route

Tags: scikit-learn, geostatistics

I have one KML file that describes the movement of a car. Data comes from sensor in the car, contains wrong or noisy measurements.
I want to filter the wrong measurements, i.e. throw away the coordinates that doesn't make sense. Coordinates points to a route that goes from one point to another point on the map and induces a route.

First thing that comes to my mind is outlier detection, but it doesn't make much sense now. Any ideas about how to start?

Comment: Ok, I added an example map hoping I would be more clear :)

Comment: Ok, it looks like an outlier detection maybe:) Any ideas about "statistics of a path"?

Comment: I assume these data are time-series stamped. Could you show us the actual paths with respect to time? Does the bad data jump around randomly, or does it create a zigzag path (for example). You could, for example, throw out the 2nd of two consecutive points where the speed required to go from point 1 to point 2 would be ludicrously high.

Comment: Hi @barrycarter , thanks for the answer firstly. I added a second image of the real path extracted from this data. Secondly, no there are no time stamps. It's a kml file and it consists of list of coordinates only.

Comment: OK, are the coordinates in order?

Comment: It looks yes to me. It looks sorted in x, then y.

Comment: Oh, but not in order that they were driven... OK, that makes it harder.

Comment: OK Barry, I looked at the data carefully again :) It looks like sorted to me, after your past I looked at again and it's not completely sorted actually, I think it's as you said, chronologically ordered which makes sense. Otherwise it would be too difficult.

Comment: So you could now look at consecutive points to see if they're too far apart to be reasonable? Since you're willing to share the paths, would you be willing to share the data too? Might help if we can look at it?

Comment: Sure, I downloaded it from a public data source.:)

Comment: I looked over this data, and noticed there are a lot of consecutive lines that are duplicates, but that shouldn't cause any problems (just an observation). I'm 99% sure I *can't* help, but if you could point us to the source, maybe there's something there that explains why this data is odd.

Comment: Did you try a simple moving average? Can you show us some data?

Comment: There are many versions of this question on [GIS.se], *q.v.*  One crucial element is whether you have a digital representation of the route(s) the car might be trying to follow: do you?

Comment: Hi @Zen , I applied a simplistic MAD (median absolute deviation) to filter the outlier points. Data is in  http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=07746862055735465840

Comment: @whuber yes I have as a list of points.